# How to test the accessibility object of a windows form application?

Tags: winforms, accessibility, microsoft-accessibility

In WindowsForms each control having the AccessibilityObject. If its a custom control derived from a Control then its also having the AccessibilityObject.

How can i test the accessibility object of the custom control in windows forms.
Is there any testing tools is available to test the accessibility object?

```
protected override AccessibleObject CreateAccessibilityInstance()
{
    if (accessibilityEnabled)
    {
        return new CustomControlAccessiblity(this);
    }
    return base.CreateAccessibilityInstance();
}
```

What is the usage of the custom accessibility object and how it can be used in the accessibility aids?